# Method in calculating distance from a point ta a line in 3D rectangle coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-systems

I have a problem while trying to calculating the distance form point $B(0,3,4)$ to the y-axis in xyz coordinate system. Here is how I calculate it:

There is point $Y(0,t,0)$ belonging to the y-axis so the vector $YB$ will be $(0,3-t,4)$.

Vector $YB$ must be perpendicular to y-axis which mean the dot product of $YB(0,3-t,4)$ with $OY(0,t,0)$ must be zero:
$$
 t(3-t) = 0
$$
So $t=0$ or $t=3$. The problem is here, by using graph I can calculate the distance between $B$ and y-axis is 4 which means
$$
 \sqrt{(3-t)^2+4^2} = 4
$$
So $t$ must be 3 only, but the result shows that $t=0$ or $t=3$. There is no way $t=0$, but I don't find any problem with the method I used.

Answer (score 1):

If $t=0$ then $OY$ is $(0,0,0)$. So $OY.v = 0$ for all vectors $v$, but that doesn't make $OY$ a solution. Instead of using $OY=(0,t,0)$, you should have used a *guaranteed non-zero* vector parallel to the $y$-axis, such as (for instance) $(0,1,0)$.

Comment: So that means in such similar cases that result in more than one value of t and some values of t make one of two vector considered be zero vector then those values of t aren't taken into account?

Comment: Obviously not all vectors $v$ are perpendicular to the $y$-axis! Think it through a little.